# Embedded UICollectionView in View Controller not getting called Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

For some strange reason the collectionView isn't called. I put break points at numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAtIndexPath but they are never called. Here is my code:

```
class ChannelViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  var channelArray: [ChannelInfo] = []
  var filteredSearchResults = [ChannelInfo]()
  var resultsSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
  var logosShown = [Bool](count: 50, repeatedValue: false)
  var detailUrl: String?
  var apiKey = ""
  var channel: String!
  var channelForShow: String!
  var task: NSURLSessionTask?

  @IBOutlet var channelCollectionView: UICollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    let baseURL = ""
    getJSON(baseURL)
  }


  //MARK: CollectionView

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if resultsSearchController.active && resultsSearchController.searchBar.text != ""
    {
      return filteredSearchResults.count
    } else {
      return channelArray.count
    }
  }


 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ChannelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChannelCell
    let channel: String
    if resultsSearchController.active && resultsSearchController.searchBar.text != "" {
      channel = self.filteredSearchResults[indexPath.row].logo
    } else {
      channel = self.channelArray[indexPath.row].logo
    }
    return cell
  }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var replacedTitle: String?
    if resultsSearchController.active && resultsSearchController.searchBar.text != "" {

      channelForShow = filteredSearchResults[indexPath.row].channelName

      }
    } else {
      channelForShow = self.channelArray[indexPath.row].channelName
      }
    }
    self.dismissSearchBar()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("channelCollectToShowSegue", sender: self)
  }
```

}

I also have a cell subclassed for the collectionView Cell:

```
class ChannelCell : UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet var channelImageView: UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: Where r u setting the datasource and delegate of the collectionView

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the datasource of collection view to the controller.

1) **In Interface builder**, just drag from the collection view to the controller. and choose both the delegate and datasource..

[image]
[image]

2) **Programatically**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    channelCollectionView.delegate = self
    channelCollectionView.dataSource = self

   let baseURL = ""
    getJSON(baseURL)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the collectionView's delegate and dataSource properties? If not, change your viewDidLoad to this, in order to set those two properties programmatically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    channelCollectionView.delegate = self
    channelCollectionView.dataSource = self
    let baseURL = ""
    getJSON(baseURL)
}
```

If you don't set the delegate and dataSource, the collectionView won't know where to look to call the appropriate methods, such as cellForItemAtIndexPath. Hopefully this fixes your problem.